# x86_64 relative jmp operand

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I can't understand how the operand `FE FC FF FF` results to *0x9e7080*.

I tried some math sub/add to the current address, because it should be relative jump, but the result still not equal to *0x9e7080*.

```
instruction address | bytes | text form

L_009E737D | E9 FE FC FF FF | jmp 0x9e7080
```

Comment: 009E737D + FFFFFCFE + 5 = 9e7080, the math checks out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things to consider:

1. `FEFCFFFF` is given as little endian and represents a hex value of `0xFFFFFCFE`.
2. This hex value is sign extended and is thus negative with a decimal value of `-770`.
3. You also have to add the number of bytes the instruction takes.

This leads to `0x009E737D + 0xFFFFFCFE + 5 = 0x009e7080`, which equals `0x009E737D - 0x00000302 + 5 = 0x009e7080`.

Comment: 0x009E737D + 0xFFFFFCFE + 5 = 1009e7080.

Comment: That would be 33 (or more) bit math, without using sign-extension.

Comment: ah sorry it's in two's complement, im noob